# AppSync Cloudformation template generator

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-appsync

I have been using the cloudformer template within Cloudformation to generate a template for AWS resources. I notice it does create the template with DynamoDB tables and some other resources but does not create one for AppSync, Lambda, and IAM roles. Is there a way to auto generate the cloudformation template from an existing AppSync schema and other resources? Would I have to use the designer tool within CloudFormation to create the stack/template and copy over the schema/template and resources by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no utility available to auto generate the cloudformation template from existing account resources. The best option is to use the Cloudformation designer to construct all resource definitions. The schema can be uploaded to S3 and the designer needs to be updated to point to it to load.